# Xcode 8 iOS 10 archiving/uploading to TestFlight takes very long

Tags: xcode8, testflight

Since I updated to XCode 8, it takes a long time archiving/uploading an app to TestFlight. While preparing archive (right after I press "Upload to Appstore"and select the appropriate Apple account), it starts Codesigning all the frameworks included in the project (I am using Cocoapods).

Any help would be highly appreciated as I am managing around 10 different accounts and it wastes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to create ipa file,

- right click your Archive and select show in finder
- Again right click on resulted file in finder and select show package content
- from result open product folder --> Application folder --> and select ".app" file
- Simply add this .app file under apps of iTunes software on mac
- After completing adding process right click on app icon in iTunes and show in finder which will give you iPA file.